# mysql search weight to result

Tags: mysql, sql

Database entries

table test

```
 name
========================
 Sunae Kasimov
 Obsop Natty
 Preem Kuman
```

Mysql query

```
select * 
from test 
where name like 'na%' or 
      name like '% na%' or 
      name like '%na%';
```

return in order
1 and then 2
but i wanted in order 2 and 1. That is want to give more weight to '% na%' then '%na%'

Any way this can be done in mysql?

Comment: how to do you measure the search "weight"?

Comment: results with '% na%' should come above '%na%', that's how i want to weight the results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
select * from name where name like '% na%'
union
select * from name where name like 'na%'
union
select * from name where name like '%na%'
) a
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create virtual filed in your select and order by it. For example:

```
select test.*,
case when name like '% na%'
         then 1
     else 2
end as OrderField
from test 
where name like 'na%' or 
      name like '% na%' or 
      name like '%na%'
order by OrderField
```